# Struts2 + Jquery Library - What is wrong on this AJAX call?

Tags: ajax, struts2, struts, javabeans

Im trying some ajax call with Struts2 and the JQuery library. This is the code of the jsp :

```
<s:div id="my_result" >
    Nothing
</s:div>

<s:form action="UserManager" theme="simple">
    <s:textfield name="nickname" />
    <s:password name="password" />
    <s:label cssClass="menu_span">
        <sj:submit targets="my_result" value="Login" />
    </s:label>
</s:form>
```

this is the code of the bean/action with the xml :

```
public class UserManager extends ActionSupport {
    private String nickname;
    private String password;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        String output="i have insered "+this.getNickname()+" and "+this.getPassword();
        System.out.println(output);
        return output;
    }

    public String getNickname() { return nickname; }
    public void setNickname(String newValue) { nickname=newValue; }

    public String getPassword() { return password; }
    public void setPassword(String newValue) { password=newValue; }
}

<package name="model" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="UserManager" class="model.UserManager">
        <result>index.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

If i `return SUCCESS` on the UserManager bean, it load on `my_result` the same calling page. Else, if i `return output` i get `Messages:

No result defined for action model.UserManager and result i have insered aaa and bbb`
 messagge (with nickname=aaa and password=bbb).

What's happened? How can i return that string? I think it's a struts.xml fault

Cheers

**UPDATE**

public class UserManager extends ActionSupport {
    private String nickname;
    private String password;
    private String error;

```
@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
    error="i have insered "+this.getNickname()+" and "+this.getPassword();
    return SUCCESS;
}

public String getNickname() { return nickname; }
public void setNickname(String newValue) { nickname=newValue; }

public String getPassword() { return password; }
public void setPassword(String newValue) { password=newValue; }

public String getError() { return error; }
public void setError(String newValue) { error=newValue; }
}

<s:div id="my_result" >
    <s:property value="error" />
</s:div>

<s:form action="UserManager" theme="simple">
    <s:textfield name="nickname" />
    <s:password name="password" />
    <s:label cssClass="menu_span">
        <sj:submit targets="my_result" value="Login" />
    </s:label>
</s:form>
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
<package name="model" extends="json-default">
    <action name="UserManager" class="model.UserManager">
        <result type="json" />
    </action>
</package>
```

Comment: Yes, but i still have a problem. Check the comment :)

Comment: I've commented again the answer

Comment: Question edited and commented again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value that you return in the execute() method must be one of the mapped as values.
As you have not a result name like this:

```
<result name="resultName"></result>
```

It will use the default one: "success". You have to return "success" value in execute() method.

The result value of the execute method is the name of the result mapped. To send a message you have to add a String attribute in your Action (and a getter to obtain it), and in the execute method do something like

```
 this.message = "my message";
```

**Edit: how to get the message with ajax:**
If you have set the message in your action in an attribute called "String message" and you have a getter for that attribute (public String getMessage()) you can get this information accesing this property in the object you get in the ajax call. If you do the ajax call for example with jquery you can get it in this way:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/yourAjaxUrl',
    success: function(data) {
       var message = data.message;
       alert('The message is '+message);
       $('#my_result').html(message);
    }
});
```

**Edit:**
In the struts xml in your package tag you have to define the json type:

```
<result-types>
    <result-type name="json" class="com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONResult">
    ...
</result-types>
```

and add the json-plugin.jar which can be downloaded [here](http://code.google.com/p/jsonplugin/downloads/list)

more info in http://code.google.com/p/jsonplugin/wiki/Documentation

Comment: Thanks, nice. But how can i print the result value in `my_result` div?

Comment: I see your example. But i still don't understand how to get only the messagge on my div `my_result`, and not the whole div (using Struts2 not Jquery directly). How can I do it? Check the UPDATE above. It return the messagge (YES, it DOES) but it return the whole page (index.jsp) on `my_result` div (and i don't want this).

Comment: In fact, what i would like to do is reload only the div called `my_result`, not the whole page. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: By reading documentation, i read `'targets' is a list of element ids whose content will be updated with the text returned from request.`, but it load the WHOLE page on the id (thats `my_result`). So i think i need to change somethings on .xml... and as "result" dont use the jsp page

Comment: If you want to get by ajax only the information and you don't want to download the whole page you have to return the information in json or xml. For json in the <result/> tag there's a type attribute where you can mark it as json result <result type="json" />
. Here there is an example: http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-and-json-example/ Then you will be able to get the message information in the same way I indicate above (by doing data.message).

Comment: Nice. I've added the library, changed the struts.xml (you can see in my last update), but i get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextUtils` . Why?

Comment: @markzzz Have you added xwork.jar library to the project? You can download it here: http://www.findjar.com/class/com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/TextUtils.html

Comment: OH, no. What is this library? And why I need it? Also, if i put that library, the application don't start (ERROR 500). I really need this?

Comment: Like `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.opensymphony.xwork2.util`... I've add xwork-2.1.2.jar

Comment: Seems that jsonplugin-0.34 have some problems with xwork-2.1.2

Comment: With xwork-core-2.1.5.jar still get the same error (`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextUtils`)

Comment: I have look at a project working and I have xwork-2.1.2.jar and jsonplugin-0.34.jar working without any problem. I've edited the question showing how is configured the plugin. Don't forget that you should add the libraries to the lib folder and in your project/properties/Java build path/libraries you should add the jars in case all the jars of you lib folder are not added automatically.

Comment: strange. I just removed all Libs, and i put the struts-json-plugins, and looks that works. Dunno, but when i start the server, i get tons of errors (about line of code that i've removed time ago). Looks that Tomcat doesnt update the actual xml files...

Comment: @markzzz if you change something in the xml you'll always have to restart tomcat